# Asking about how to connect database in RESTful web service in java

Tags: java, mongodb, service

I am doing a RESTful web service in java. But I can't run it successfully. exception occurs. Could anyone give my suggestion? I use mongo db as a database

```
@Path("/test")
public class test {

    mongoDAO mongodao;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html,text/plain")
    public String getContainer(){

        mongoDAOImpl impl=new mongoDAOImpl();
        Mongo mongo=impl.getConnection("127.0.0.1","27017");
        DB db=impl.getDataBase(mongo,"public");
        DBCollection coll=impl.getColl(db,"public");
        mongoDTO dto=new mongoDTO();
        dto.setParentpath("/home/public/liren");
        dto.setUserName("liren");
        dto.setPassWord("liren");

   // System.out.println("In PathResource.getContainer, path is: " + path);
    //print headers for debug
  //  for (String hdr : headers.getRequestHeaders().keySet()) {
  //    System.out.println("Hdr: "+ hdr + " - " + headers.getRequestHeader(hdr));
  //  }

    try{
        //DBObject dbobject=mongodao.findOneRecord(coll, dto);
        DBCursor dbcur=mongodao.findAllRecords(coll);
        while(dbcur.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(dbcur.next());
        }
//        if(dbobject==null){
//            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
//        }else{
            //return Response.ok().header("Specification-version", "1.0").build();
        return "Ok";
//        }
    }
        catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
        //return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).tag("Container Read Error : " + ex.toString()).build();
                return "Sorry Exception, try again!";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you detail which exception is thrown? Usually having the stacktrace is very helpful.

Comment: It would also be helpful to trim out all of the commented out code...

Comment: when I test the web service in NetBeans, the result is "404 Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that mongodao is null, thus `DBCursor dbcur=mongodao.findAllRecords(coll);` will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: when I test the web service in NetBeans, the result is "404 Not Found"